# Unable to use pytest parameterize functionality to update the YAML config

Tags: pytest, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml module to update the YAML using python.
I wanted to use pytest parameterize functionality to update the YAML config.

Here is the `test.yaml` file:

```
TestConfig:
  hostname: 10.2.4.6
  Organisation:
    Employee:
      Name: Smriti
      Skilss: Python 
      OrganizationName: ABC
      UserId: smriti_test@gmail.com
```

Here is the conftest file so that we need to not to explicitly import the fixture functionality:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def yaml_loader(request):
   yaml = YAML()
   file_path = 'test.yaml'
   with open(file_path) as fp:
      data = yaml.load(fp)
      test = data['TestConfig']
      x = request.param
      print(x)
   with open(file_path, "w") as file:
      yaml.dump(data, file)
   print(data)
```

Here is the implementation of sample testfile for running the test and using the fixture from conftest and update the config in YAML and perform the test.

```
import pytest

class TestYAML:
    """ TestYAML """
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("yaml_loader",[("test['Organisation']['Employee']\
                                            ['Name']='Arushi'")],indirect=True)
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("yaml_loader")
    def test_update_yamlconfig(self):
        pass
```

In the result I am seeing the x is printing the updated Value of Name to Arushi but in the YAML file the config is not updating.

Comment: AFAICT you are not changing anything in the "data" data-structure hierarchy. do you ant to do somtehting like `data['TestConfig'] = request.param` ?

Comment: I tried this but this is only updating the yaml with the config provided in fixtures parameterize.
Though I want the yaml will have the initial config and just modify or update the config to the keys which i wanted to using parameterization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of tries i am able to find the solution to this question.

So Here is the updated code for reference:-
For test file i have taken two different param and i will assign that param individually when i call the fixtures and this has worked

### test_yaml.py

```
import pytest

class TestYAML:
    """ TestYAML """
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("yaml_loader", 
                           [("hostname","10.5.6.8")],indirect=True)
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("yaml_loader")
    def test_update_yamlconfig(self):
        pass
```

Here is the updated conftest where i have defined the fixture:-

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def yaml_loader(request):
   yaml = YAML()
   file_path = 'test.yaml'
   file_path1 = 'my.yaml'
   with open(file_path) as fp:
      data = yaml.load(fp)
      test = data['TestConfig']
      test[request.param[0]] = request.param[1]
   with open(file_path1, "w") as file:
       yaml.dump(data, file)
   print(data)
```

And you will get the output as :-

```
platform linux -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- 
/mnt/c/Users/smaheshw/PycharmProjects/YAML/venv/bin/python3.8
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /mnt/c/Users/smaheshw/PycharmProjects/YAML
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                           

test_yaml.py::TestYAML::test_update_yamlconfig[yaml_loader0] Request parameters
hostname
ordereddict([('TestConfig', ordereddict([('hostname', '10.5.6.8'), ('Organisation', 
ordereddict([('Employee', ordereddict([('Name', 'Smriti'), ('Skilss', 'Python'), 
('OrganizationName', 'A
BC'), ('UserId', 'smriti_test@gmail.com')]))]))]))])
PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with pytest not behaving as you want, you should take a step back and make sure
your `yaml_laoder()` function does what you expect:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml_str = """\
TestConfig:
  hostname: 10.2.4.6
  Organisation:
    Employee:
      Name: Smriti
      Skilss: Python 
      OrganizationName: ABC
      UserId: smriti_test@gmail.com
"""

Path('test.yaml').write_text(yaml_str)  # write out the file so that it is fresh every time

class R: pass
r = R()
r.param = "XXXXXX"

def yaml_loader(request):
   yaml = YAML()
   file_path = 'test.yaml'
   with open(file_path) as fp:
      data = yaml.load(fp)
      test = data['TestConfig']
      x = request.param
      print(x)
   with open(file_path, "w") as file:
      yaml.dump(data, file)
   print(data)

yaml_loader(r)

print('\n######### YAML #########\n')
print(Path('test.yaml').read_text())
```

which gives:

```
XXXXXX
ordereddict([('TestConfig', ordereddict([('hostname', '10.2.4.6'), ('Organisation', ordereddict([('Employee', ordereddict([('Name', 'Smriti'), ('Skilss', 'Python'), ('OrganizationName', 'ABC'), ('UserId', 'smriti_test@gmail.com')]))]))]))])

######### YAML #########

TestConfig:
  hostname: 10.2.4.6
  Organisation:
    Employee:
      Name: Smriti
      Skilss: Python
      OrganizationName: ABC
      UserId: smriti_test@gmail.com
```

As you can clearly sea from the YAML content, it never gets updated with `XXXXXX`. This is because you don't assign to `data`
before writing out the `test.yaml` file.

Fix that first and then inject the code into your test.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. However, if you just check the conftest if you add            
test = data['TestConfig']
test['hostname'] = '10.5.6.5'                                                                                             where i am updating the test locally into the function then it is updating the YAML as expected, However not able to take the parameterize functionality to update the config.